# portable transistor radio

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics

I recently bought a cheap (@ US$7) transistor radio, with an FM band, an AM band, 4 SW bands, and 2 VHF (tv **audio**) bands covering channels 1 to 13.  However, i later discovered that i couldn't tune in to the last station in the AM band (1602 kHz).

I noticed that there are a few variable resistors in its circuit board.  Can i adjust the AM band limits by adjusting one or more of the variable resistor(s) so that i can tune in to the 'missing' station?  If so, how do i know which variable resistor to adjust?

Comment: This question is better suited for [electronics.se].

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "maybe" and you will not know which one to adjust, if any, without a circuit diagram. Just record their positions so you can undo any changes you make, and experiment. As you said - it's cheap.